# How to add an icon into header and cells in @silevis/reactgrid

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the way to add an icon to the header and cells?

```
import { ReactGrid, Column, Row } from "@silevis/reactgrid";

const headerRow: Row = {
  rowId: "header",
  cells: [
    { type: "header", text: "<Icon.Arrow>text" },
    { type: "header", text: "Value" }
  ]
};
const getRows = (charges): Row[] => [
  headerRow,
  ...charges.map<Row>((charge, idx) => ({
    rowId: idx,
    cells: [
      { type: "text", text: "<Icon.Arrow>some text" },
      { type: "text", text: "some text" },

    ]
  }))
];
<ReactGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} />
```

Trying to add an icon with the text in the header and cells but it is resulting into

`[object object] some text`